# how to get image map from Jfree chart's Image

Tags: java, html, charts, jasper-reports, jfreechart

In bar chart, I want to use hyperlinks for every color(or segment). To make this I need to use Image MAP (using Jfree chart).
My code is creating image through Jfree chart, but I also want individual hyperlink with every color code.
Can you please advice how I can get coordinates from Jfree chart's image based on color code or row key or column key.

public class Demo 
{

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException{

    DefaultCategoryDataset result = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

     result.addValue(20.3, "Apraisal Forms", "Dtest");
        result.addValue(19.4, "Resignation  Form", "Dtest");
        result.addValue(16.5, "HES forms", "Dtest");
        result.addValue(8, "Feedback forms", "Dtest");

        result.addValue(27.2, "Apraisal Forms", "HR Dept");
        result.addValue(5.9, "Resignation  Form", "HR Dept");
        result.addValue(14.4, "Feedback forms", "HR Dept");
        result.addValue(4, "HES forms", "HR Dept");

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart3D("overview by Departments", "x label", "Message Count", result, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, true);

    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File("D:\\chart.jpg"), chart, 500, 300);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I can get the image through >>
ChartUtilities.getImageMap("chart",info);
*********************************************************

But it returns string like this>>>

<map id="chart" name="chart">
<area shape="rect" coords="526,233,553,334" title="(HES forms, Business Dept) = 25" alt="" href="/saveData?series=HES+forms&amp;category=Business+Dept"/>
</map>
**********************************************************

But i want to add my own HREF values. so how can I do that instead of doing PITY code (by replacing href old value to new value)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it done by implementing `ToolTipTagFragmentGenerator` and `URLTagFragmentGenerator`. Here is the full code:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {

        DefaultCategoryDataset result = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        result.addValue(20.3, "Apraisal Forms", "Dtest");
        result.addValue(19.4, "Resignation  Form", "Dtest");
        result.addValue(16.5, "HES forms", "Dtest");
        result.addValue(8, "Feedback forms", "Dtest");

        result.addValue(27.2, "Apraisal Forms", "HR Dept");
        result.addValue(5.9, "Resignation  Form", "HR Dept");
        result.addValue(14.4, "Feedback forms", "HR Dept");
        result.addValue(4, "HES forms", "HR Dept");

        result.addValue(18.4, "Resignation  Form", "Admin Dept");
        result.addValue(16.1, "HES forms", "Admin Dept");
        result.addValue(13.7, "Feedback forms", "Admin Dept");

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart3D(
            "overview by Departments", "x label", "Message Count", result,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, true);

        SubCategoryAxis domainAxis = new SubCategoryAxis("Name of Department");
        domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(0.60);

        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);

        String map = "";

        ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(
            new StandardEntityCollection());

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, chart, 600, 400, info);

            ToolTipTagFragmentGenerator tooltipConstructor = new ToolTipTagFragmentGenerator() {
                public String generateToolTipFragment(String arg0) {
                    String toolTip = " title = \"value" + arg0 + "\"";
                    return (toolTip);
                }
            };

            URLTagFragmentGenerator urlConstructor = new URLTagFragmentGenerator() {
                public String generateURLFragment(String arg0) {
                    String address = " href=\"ControllerAddress\\methodName?"
                        + arg0 + "\"";
                    return (address);
                }
            };

            map = ChartUtilities.getImageMap("chart", info, tooltipConstructor,
                urlConstructor);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println(map);
        ChartFrame frame1 = new ChartFrame("Bar Chart", chart);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setSize(600, 350);
    }
}
```